# Is the calculated solution, if it exists, unique?

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, least-squares

I am looking the following:

We have the system of equations \begin{equation*}Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & -4 \\ 3 & 9 & -2 \\ 4 & 12 & -6 \\ 2 & 6 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=b\end{equation*} 
Calculate the system $Ax=b$ with the least squares method. Is the calculated solution, if it exists (show that!), unique?

$$$$

I have done the following:

To solve the system by the least squares method we solve the system $A^TA\overline{x} = A^Tb$. Using the Gauss-Algorithm we get the solution $\overline{x}=\begin{pmatrix}-2.4 \\ 1 \\ -0.1\end{pmatrix}$.

About the second part of the question, what exactly is meant? Since we have calculated a solution, how can we show if a solution exists? Or have I understood the question wrong?

Comment: An effective way to show existence of a solution is to produce one. You’ve done that. There’s still the other half of that question to address: are there any other solutions?

Comment: Ah ok! How could we check if the solution is unique? @amd

Comment: You used Gaussian elimination to find a solution, so presumably you have a row-reduced echelon form matrix in hand. Do you remember how to tell from that how many solutions there are?

Comment: Since there is no zero-row at the row-reduced echelon form the solution is unique, right? @amd

Comment: That’s right. Another way to view this is that the least-squares solution is basically a projection onto the column space of $A$, which is unique.

Comment: Does this mean that it is unique if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent? @amd

Comment: Yes, since otherwise $A^TA$ will be singular.

Comment: Ah I see!! I have also an other question. It is also asked if the system would be solvable for $b=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)^T$. How could we check this? Do we have to calculate it or is there an other way?  @amd

Comment: Which system? The original or the least-squares? By construction, the latter can always be solved—that’s kind of the whole point of the procedure. The equation $Ax=b$ has a solution iff $b\in\operatorname{Col}(A)$, but unless you can determine this by inspection, the way you’d check that is essentially to try to solve the system.

Comment: So, do we have to check if there are $x,y,z$ such that \begin{equation*}x\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 2\\ 0\end{pmatrix} + y\cdot \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 9 \\ 12 \\ 6 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+z\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-4 \\ -2 \\ -6 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} ? @amd

Comment: So, in other words we have to solve the system and chec kif there is a solution, or not? @amd

Answer (score 2):

What you might find useful, is to try finding a **non-trivial** $y \ne 0$ solution of $Ay = 0$. If such $y$ exists, then for any constant $C$ the solution $x$ of the equation $Ax = b$ is not unique, since

$$
A(x + Cy) = Ax + C Ay = Ax + C \cdot 0 = Ax = b
$$

which presumes non-uniqueness.

Otherwise, if there is no such $y: Ay = 0$, other then $y = 0$, then your solution is unique.

Comment: I understand!! have also an other question. It is also asked if the system would be solvable for $b=(1,1,1,1,1)^T$. How could we check this? Do we have to calculate it or is there an other way?

Answer (score 0):

[Collecting the discussion in comments into an answer.]

You’ve already proven existence of a solution by producing one. As for uniqueness, inspect the row-reduced matrix that you computed to find this solution: it has no rows without a pivot, so the solution is unique—there are no free variables in the solution.

The original system may or may not be solvable for other values of $\mathbf b$. For there to be a solution at all, we must have $\mathbf b\in\operatorname{Col}(A)$. You might be able to determine this by inspection for some values of $\mathbf b$, but in general testing this condition amounts to solving the system. On the other hand, the least-squares system $A^TA\mathbf x=A^T\mathbf b$ will always have a solution for this $A$: its columns are linearly independent, so $A^TA$ is a nonsingular square matrix, hence $(A^TA)^{-1}$ exists.